# Are the equations for the cross section in particle physics specific to box normalization of plane waves?

Tags: particle-physics

Referring to [this](http://www.hep.phy.cam.ac.uk/~thomson/lectures/partIIIparticles/Handout1_2009.pdf)

Suppose we replace the plane wave functions in this analysis with particle-in-the-box wavefunctions.  That is, imagine we are treating K-orbital electron capture, and we want to treat the electrons in 1S atomic orbitals with particle-in-the-box wavefunctions, to a first approximation.

Can we simply add the add the L.I. correction  to the normalized , classical wave function $\Psi$, as in

Slide 22

$$ \Psi_\textrm{L.I.} \sim \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{(2E)}} \Psi_\textrm{classical}  $$

Or are the arguments here specific to using plane-waves with box normalization ?

Since, for a box normalized plane waves

$$ |\Psi| \sim \dfrac{1}{V} ,$$

but for a 3D particle-in-the-box

$$ |\Psi| \sim \left(\dfrac{1}{V}\right)^{3/2} $$